# Can't transition background-color

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a transition of two different background-color's on hover.

I've looked up different solutions but none of them have worked out so far.
I have also attempted using `-webkit-transition` and `transition` and neither have worked so far.

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffdc73; /* hsl(200, 100%, 80% */
  box-shadow:
    0 7px 30px -10px #ffdc73, /* This one should usually be only box-shadow but I made it two so it would be more visable */
    0 7px 30px -10px #ffdc73;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #282936;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow:
    0 7px 30px -10px #282936, /* rgba(154,160,185,0.05) */
    0 7px 30px -10px #282936; /* rgba(166,173,201,0.2) */
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"> Buttton </a>
```

Comment: By two background colors, what do you mean? are you refering to the box-shadow and background-color?

Comment: Also your box-shadow provides a with of (-) number - that doesn't make it visible.

Comment: Instead of box-shadow in transition property put it ```all``` and remove transition in hover

Answer (score 1):

Please note:

Transitions are defined within the actual block not the event block.

e,g `a{here...}` and `a:hover{not here...}`

Below is the transition of `background-color` and `box-shadow` property of style object.

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffdc73; /* hsl(200, 100%, 80% */
  box-shadow:
    0 7px 30px -10px #ffdc73, /* This one should usually be only box-shadow but I made it two so it would be more visable */
    0 7px 30px -10px #ffdc73;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  
  transition-property: box-shadow, background-color;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #282936;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow:
    0 7px 30px 10px #282936, /* rgba(154,160,185,0.05) */
    0 7px 30px 10px #282936; /* rgba(166,173,201,0.2) */
}
```

```html
<a>Check this out</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `box-shadow` should be applied to the `:hover`, while the `transition` should be applied to the root element:

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffdc73;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #282936;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 30px -10px #282936, 0 7px 30px -10px #282936;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover over me</a>
```

Comment: this only works for box-shadow. background-color doesn't seem to transition

Comment: Just need to add `transition-property: all;` to the first CSS block

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a `background-color` transition, then change `box-shadow` in `a` style to `background-color`

```
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffdc73; /* hsl(200, 100%, 80% */
  box-shadow:
    0 7px 30px -10px #ffdc73, /* This one should usually be only box-shadow but I made it two so it would be more visable */
    0 7px 30px -10px #ffdc73;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out; /* Change transition-property from box-shadow to background-color */
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #282936;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow:
    0 7px 30px -10px #282936, /* rgba(154,160,185,0.05) */
    0 7px 30px -10px #282936; /* rgba(166,173,201,0.2) */
}
```

Comment: `a` is actually a box with text in it and I have successfully worked out the shadow and box colour transitions thanks to you guys, now is there anyway I can create a transition from the `a` `color` tag to the `a:hover` `color` tag?

Edit: Got it worked out, nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to transition the background color, you will need to include that property in you transition.

```
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffdc73; /* hsl(200, 100%, 80% */
  box-shadow:
    0 7px 30px -10px #ffdc73, /* This one should usually be only box-shadow but I made it two so it would be more visable */
    0 7px 30px -10px #ffdc73;
  transition: 
    background-color 0.3s ease-in-out,
    box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #282936;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow:
    0 7px 30px -10px #282936, /* rgba(154,160,185,0.05) */
    0 7px 30px -10px #282936; /* rgba(166,173,201,0.2) */
  transition: 
   background-color 0.3s ease-in-out,
   box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Udj72JIVEIQdQUbR